# Selecting data from one table and joining another table for the main "key" is quite slow

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, a client would search by using a username which would search the users table for the record, and the user ID and then search through the rooms table and return the results, however my current code appears to be quite slow.

I have around 750,000 records in my rooms table and around 550,000 records in my users table, so my results tend to take around 5-7 seconds to display back to the client, is there an alternative to my code below?

```
SELECT
    `rooms`.`id`,
    `rooms`.`caption`,
    `rooms`.`description`,
    `rooms`.`roomtype`,
    `rooms`.`owner`,
    `rooms`.`state`,
    `rooms`.`category`,
    `rooms`.`users_now`,
    `rooms`.`users_max`,
    `rooms`.`model_name`,
    `rooms`.`score`,
    `rooms`.`allow_pets`,
    `rooms`.`allow_pets_eat`,
    `rooms`.`room_blocking_disabled`,
    `rooms`.`allow_hidewall`,
    `rooms`.`password`,
    `rooms`.`wallpaper`,
    `rooms`.`floor`,
    `rooms`.`landscape`,
    `rooms`.`floorthick`,
    `rooms`.`wallthick`,
    `rooms`.`mute_settings`,
    `rooms`.`kick_settings`,
    `rooms`.`ban_settings`,
    `rooms`.`chat_mode`,
    `rooms`.`chat_speed`,
    `rooms`.`chat_size`,
    `rooms`.`trade_settings`,
    `rooms`.`group_id`,
    `rooms`.`tags`,
    `rooms`.`push_enabled`,
    `rooms`.`pull_enabled`,
    `rooms`.`enables_enabled`,
    `rooms`.`respect_notifications_enabled`
FROM
    `rooms`
JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `rooms`.`owner`
WHERE
    `users`.`username` = 'query'
ORDER BY
    `rooms`.`users_now` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

**Explain plan:**

```
1   SIMPLE  users   const   PRIMARY,id,username username    128 const   1   Using index
1   SIMPLE  rooms   index   owner   users_now   4       50  Using where
```

I've indexed the appropriate columns, but still seem to get slow results. Thanks!

Comment: A side note if you have many columns in your both table then donot use `*` just select the needed ones,Also post `EXPLAIN your  query` plan for your query in your question

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid sorry about that, I put * just for the post (thinking the query may look too big/cramped on here) I've updated the post.

Comment: This is good enough you also need to run [*`Explain`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) plan for your query and post the output in your question so future visitors can analyze the causes

Comment: Thank you, I've also added that (hopefully I did it correctly).

Comment: I am not familiar with MySQL to properly answer but I've seen the following to be the cause on other DBs.  1) Are your types and precision the same for users.ID and rooms.owner ?  If not then a scan will be needed due to the implicit type conversion. 2) users has some index on username where the username is first as well as one where ID is first

Comment: @LoztInSpace Thanks for your input, I've just had a quick check, the types are the same, and I believe that's just the way they're being outputted. They're both unique indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it, your results are based on the users table, but should contain data from teh rooms table. You could get your results instantly by two queries instead of one. First get your users.id, then take that result and search the rooms table for a matching owner.

```
select users.id from users where username='search'
```

Now run a whole new query for your room with the array of users.id you just got. ForEach Code depends on the scripting language you're working in.

While I admit this puts more effort on your script, it will definitely pick up your speed immediately. This will still work if your users results have multiple records (ie: if there will be multiple "users.id" records returned, this method will still be snappy by comparison). If there are multiple records, you can construct an array that looks like this to allow a single query to get all your rooms:

```
select * from rooms where owner in ('id1','id2','id3')
```

Another method is:

```
select * from rooms where owner in (select users.id from users where username='search')
```

This method is simpler and seems cheap, but works nicely. It will not return user data, just room data. The first method would allow you to capture user data on the first query and room data on the second.

Comment: Thank you for your input. From further inspection I've found an extra 2 seconds is just from sorting. I'll make the changes on my back-end and use Linq to sort the results in real-time.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you work out why the DB takes so long and fix it so the DB to does the sort in a sensible way.  Sucking a database into memory and sorting it there just causes a world of pain.

Comment: @LoztInSpace the issue seems to be the ORDER BY. I can't really think of a better solution other than to fetch the data I need and sort it in my script. I'll leave this question open for a little longer to see if anyone has anymore suggestions though. Thanks again.

Comment: Do you have an index on rooms.users_now ?  If the problem is that it's doing the sort before all the joins then try to break the use of the sort index: ORDER BY 'XX'+`rooms`.`users_now` DESC or something. If that makes it fast then usually it's down to corrupt or out of date statistics causing a wonky plan. Like I said, I am no MySQL expert but these things happen to all DBs now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks fine, and the amount of records is not all that high.

Make sure users.id and rooms.owner are both indexed.

Do you need the ORDER BY - this can cause performance issues if a filesort is required. There are a [few](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) things you can do to improve server performance if thats the case.

An EXPLAIN may help in narrowing down the issue.

Comment: Yup, it appears to be the ORDER BY causing an extra 2.5 seconds, thanks for the link, I'll take a look.